# Is there a way to radiograph through layers of underlying components

Tags: javascript, html, css, z-index, transparency

**Task description:**

There is an element which contains another element which in its turn contains another element (theoretically there can be a sequence of inner elements). The last element has background set to transparent. The task is that this transparency would go all the way down to the background of the first outer element.

So, in the example below, the background of the area of the .shouldRadiographElement should be yellow as the background of the .wrapper element.

*If some clarifications on the task are required, please, ask in comments.*

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: yellow;
}

.element {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
}

.shouldRadiographElement {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="element">
    <div class="shouldRadiographElement"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you only care about the colors or is there going to potentially be text or an image that needs to be visible?

Comment: Did you tried with the CSS `z-index` property?

Comment: @abney317 Yeah, everything that is on the outer layer should be visible (be it text or an image), so, I'm aiming to implement some kind of x-ray effect.

Comment: @GonzaloPan Yep, could not figure out how to do it with z-index... Any help is welcome ))

Comment: @olegzhermal I don't know if this will help you but you can get an idea of a solution to your problem because I can't figure out how to do it :/ https://codepen.io/noeldelgado/pen/ByxQjL

Answer (score 0):

You can use The clip-path property as following on the second Div

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: yellow;
}

.element {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 0 54%, 0 55%, 0 0, 55% 0, 56% 53%, 0 53%, 0 100%, 
  100% 100%, 100% 0%);
}

.shouldRadiographElement {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="element">
    <div class="shouldRadiographElement"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: see this site to determin what clip values you want to use  http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/